# How to solve gradlew publishReleaseBundle not working?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradlew

**Below is the error after I running the command "gradlew publishReleaseBundle" in terminal android studio.**

Configure project :app

WARNING: API 'variant.getMappingFile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMappingFileProvider()'.

It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.

To determine what is calling variant.getMappingFile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.

registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use

registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use

registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  BUNDLE
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

**Another thing to highlight:**

It also after I upgraded my Android Gradle Plugin Version to 3.6.1 and Gradle Version to 5.6.4 then the problem only occur. Is it this problem?

Please help me on this, because i cant find any solution on this.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you've fixed this by now, but this happened to me, and the answer was that old versions of the Triple-T Play Publisher plugin became incompatible with newer versions of Gradle.

Switching to TTPP version 2.5.0, the last version that was compatible with Gradle 5.6.4, resolved the issue. If that hadn't worked, I would have upgraded Gradle and used a more recent version of TTPP.

Comment: Hi bro, thank for reply and sry that now only saw ur answer.

I not solving the problem yet.

I was using publishReleaseBundle in Gitlab CICD, so I planning to re-setup all the setting for the Gitlab CICD.

I also feel that the newer version of Gradle is affect the setting of my Gitlab CICD.